# Command line installer issues

Tags: install4j

Am attempting to run installer using command line using -c option.
Command line execution appears like this:

---

E:\dev>MyApp_32.exe -c

E:\dev>This will install App on your computer.

OK [o, Enter], Cancel [c]

E:\dev>   (showing the Windows command line is confusing to user)

Welcome .. (text of 2nd screen)

---

1. Typing "c" or "Cancel" doesn't work. It always takes enter key as input and proceeds to next screen.
2. Pressing enter transfers control back to windows's command shell, then back to installer. This looks confusing to user. It doesn't give a unified experience to user.
3. Is it possible to provide input via a silent file ? i.e. a text file with pre-selected inputs?

Am using 32 bit installer on Win 7 Professional x64 with Java 1.6 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the installer is a GUI application, it cannot take control of a WIndows terminal in this way. If you start it via

```
start /wait MyApp_32.exe -c
```

the command line prompts will not be displayed.

You can run set a response file with the -varfile argument, see the [help](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/installers/responseFile.html) for more information.